# Sphinx search returns empty

Tags: php, sphinx

I am new to sphinx search, i have
PHP 7.1
centos 7.1
sphinx sphinx-2.2.1-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm

**Below is my query**

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'k***bster', '', '***', '9312');

$link->query('SELECT * FROM `prestasite` WHERE MATCH('paper') ORDER BY ord DESC LIMIT 0,10 OPTION ranker=bm25, field_weights=(name=20, reference=50, category=8, brand=8,tag=7);')
```

Result is empty

but when i try in terminal within mysql it works fine

when i check /var/log/sphinx/query.log
i saw only the queries which i run in terminal but not which i run in php code

**sphinx.conf**

```
source prestasite
{
            type = mysql

            sql_host = localhost
            sql_user = *
            sql_pass = 
            sql_db = k***hop
            sql_port = 3306 # optional, default is 3306
      sql_query = SELECT d_product,name,reference,id_category,category, id_manufacturer,brand, tag, price,score from kob_catalog_view;
            sql_attr_uint = id_category
            sql_attr_uint = id_manufacturer
            sql_attr_float = price
            sql_attr_bigint = scoresource prestasite
}

index prestasite
{
            source = prestasite
            path = /var/lib/sphinx/test1
}

indexer
{
            mem_limit = 128M
}


searchd
{
            listen = localhost:9312
            listen = localhost:9306:mysql41
            log = /var/log/sphinx/searchd.log
            query_log = /var/log/sphinx/query.log
            read_timeout = 5
            max_children = 30
            pid_file = /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid
            seamless_rotate = 1
            preopen_indexes = 1
            unlink_old = 1
            workers = threads # for RT to work
            binlog_path = /var/lib/sphinx
}
```

Comment: You should probably try checking for errors, after trying to connect. You at the moment dont catch connection errors, so dont know if the connection fails, and/or the query fails http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Oh, but in your listen, you have spinxAPI on port 9312, and sphinxQL on 9306. But you try connecting using mysql clinet on 9312, should be using port 9306!!!

Comment: @barryhunter you are right i changed port to 9306 as well as changed to localhost to 127.0.0.1 below is my code now $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'password', 'db', '9306');